# domain redirect working sporadically

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

When I go to my site's domain, it redirects to the WWW subdomain, which isn't what I want.  It also just takes me to the domain registrar's like "page coming" page.

I did a CNAME change for the DNS of my domain, I set up a wordpress, I made a file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ that looked like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerName $MYSERVERNAME.tld
        ServerAlias www.$MYSERVERNAME.tld
        ServerAdmin $MYEMAILADDRESS
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

         <Directory /var/www/html/>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        </Directory>
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

my .htaccess file (which should redirect www to non-www):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

i can provide more info including the domain if necessary

Comment: Domain changes may not have propagated yet.

Comment: Meanwhile you can test with: `curl -I --resolve www.example.com:80:127.0.0.1 http://www.example.com:80/` substituting the appropriate IP.

Comment: You did restart/reload apache?  Your .htaccess file is being respected?

Comment: `host -t a www.example.com` and the same without the www, should point to the same IPv4 addreses.  You can test your DNS changes by placing your nameserver's IP after; `host -t a www.example.com 1.2.3.4`

Comment: ok I think I fixed it.  working for now.   I didn't even think of the hosts file until you mentioned it

Comment: 127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       username.username username

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

myIPaddress    i had my domain here but I needed to change it to username.username username just like the one above